# How to adjust labels' font size to size of the bars in ggplot2?

Tags: r, ggplot2, geom-text

Good morning,

I have a `ggplot2` bar graph inside a loop, in which the size of bars changes in every run of the loop:

```
ggplot(draft, aes(x=draft[,2], y=draft[,i])) +
      geom_bar(stat="identity",fill="navyblue") + 
      geom_text(label=draft[,i],size=4, vjust=1.2, colour = "white",fontface=2) +
      labs(title = paste("Session trends for",colnames(draft)[i],"-",player))+
      theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 0,color="black",size=8),
            axis.title.x = element_blank(),
            axis.title.y = element_blank(),
            plot.title = element_text(color="black", size=10, face="bold",hjust = 0.5),
            legend.position = "none",panel.grid.major = element_blank(), panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),panel.background = element_blank(), axis.line = element_line(colour = "black"))
```

In the `geom_text` part (labels of the bars), as you can see, `size=4`. This is fine for some graphs, but it is too big/small for others. My question is:

**Is there any way to adjust the font size automatically to the size of the bar?**

Thank you very much in advance.

**Reproducible example.**
This is the dataframe from where I represent the data:

```
> dput(draft)
structure(list(Player = c("Shaquil Delos", "Shaquil Delos", "Shaquil Delos", 
"Shaquil Delos", "Shaquil Delos", "Shaquil Delos", "Shaquil Delos", 
"Shaquil Delos", "Shaquil Delos", "Shaquil Delos", "Shaquil Delos", 
"Shaquil Delos", "Shaquil Delos", "Shaquil Delos", "Shaquil Delos", 
"Shaquil Delos"), Date = structure(c(19371, 19370, 19369, 19368, 
19367, 19364, 19363, 19362, 19361, 19360, 19359, 19356, 19355, 
19354, 19353, 19349), class = "Date"), week = c(29, 29, 29, 29, 
29, 28, 28, 28, 28, 28, 28, 27, 27, 27, 27, 26), TD = c(6638, 
2660, 4761, 4956, 3984, 4001, 3688, 4476, 4616, 4666, 4120, 3782, 
3701, 4398, 4275, 3222), Time = c(96, 67, 70, 75, 38, 33, 55, 
68, 59, 57, 56, 35, 45, 56, 46, 21), Vmax = c(9.4, 4.7, 8.3, 
8.8, 6.9, 9.5, 6.5, 6, 9.2, 7.1, 7.3, 9, 6.5, 6.8, 6.2, 4.6), 
    Amax = c(4.5, 3.1, 4.1, 4.9, 3.8, 3.8, 4.4, 3.9, 4.5, 4.4, 
    4, 3.4, 4.3, 3.5, 3.2, 1.5), Dmax = c(-5.9, -2.8, -4.2, -6.2, 
    -3.9, -2.7, -4.9, -3.5, -2.7, -4.6, -3.5, -2.7, -4.5, -3.7, 
    -3.8, -1.4), Aerobic = c(462, 44, 589, 280, 175, 546, 333, 
    831, 303, 959, 225, 125, 194, 188, 534, 665), HSD = c(177, 
    0, 475, 86, 59, 463, 56, 14, 384, 92, 119, 393, 54, 262, 
    24, 0), SD = c(100, 0, 78, 39, 0, 149, 0, 0, 125, 3, 6, 141, 
    0, 0, 0, 0), Nsprints = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), DEC3 = c(7, 0, 2, 5, 0, 
    0, 8, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0), ACC3 = c(4, 0, 1, 4, 0, 
    0, 9, 0, 3, 4, 0, 0, 9, 0, 0, 0), RHIE = c(15, 3, 19, 10, 
    5, 5, 17, 6, 6, 10, 10, 3, 10, 5, 5, 2), MIP1 = c(161, 112, 
    169, 147, 184, 285, 162, 266, 170, 248, 197, 222, 167, 177, 
    232, 254), MIP3 = c(359, 309, 375, 345, 535, 738, 431, 688, 
    479, 709, 531, 549, 476, 461, 662, 724), MIP5 = c(565, 473, 
    560, 537, 868, 1049, 589, 851, 673, 1152, 845, 875, 682, 
    619, 983, 1166), ACC = c(78, 14, 64, 46, 27, 20, 51, 32, 
    29, 56, 40, 12, 45, 26, 21, 0), ACC2 = c(18, 1, 14, 15, 3, 
    9, 24, 9, 16, 12, 9, 6, 25, 4, 3, 0), DEC = c(67, 11, 42, 
    48, 23, 14, 36, 22, 14, 49, 32, 7, 30, 20, 15, 0), DEC2 = c(21, 
    0, 12, 14, 5, 0, 20, 4, 0, 11, 4, 0, 16, 1, 2, 0), Explosive = c(12, 
    9, 15, 13, 5, 1, 45, 11, 3, 8, 16, 0, 14, 11, 6, 0), TRIMP = c(107, 
    0, 78, 51, 105, 60, 85, 93, 55, 93, 102, 44, 89, 110, 109, 
    47), TRIMP4 = c(0, 0, 3, 12, 20, 8, 0, 0, 0, 13, 1, 2, 2, 
    15, 17, 15), TRIMP5 = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0), TD.min = c(69.3, 39.9, 68.1, 66, 103.6, 121.4, 
    67.2, 65.7, 78.7, 82.1, 77.5, 109.3, 82.5, 78.8, 92.8, 151
    ), HRavg = c(66, 0, 65, 65, 79, 69, 67, 65, 60, 67, 74, 70, 
    71, 71, 75, 73), Vmax.perc = c(100, 50, 88, 93, 73, 101, 
    69, 64, 98, 75, 78, 95, 70, 72, 66, 49), Amax.perc = c(88, 
    62, 80, 96, 74, 75, 86, 77, 89, 87, 78, 67, 85, 68, 63, 30
    ), Dmax.perc = c(104, 50, 74, 109, 69, 48, 85, 61, 47, 81, 
    61, 47, 79, 65, 66, 25)), row.names = c("21", "211", "22", 
"19", "191", "2", "20", "212", "201", "213", "221", "1", "11", 
"202", "203", "18"), class = "data.frame")
```

And this is the bars graph I am building:

```
ggplot(draft, aes(x=draft[,2], y=draft[,1])) +
      geom_bar(stat="identity",fill="navyblue") + 
      geom_text(label=draft[,i],size=4, vjust=1.2, colour = "white",fontface=2) +
      labs(title = paste("Session trends for",colnames(draft)[1],"-",player))+
      theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 0,color="black",size=8),
            axis.title.x = element_blank(),
            axis.title.y = element_blank(),
            plot.title = element_text(color="black", size=10, face="bold",hjust = 0.5),
            legend.position = "none",panel.grid.major = element_blank(), panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),panel.background = element_blank(), axis.line = element_line(colour = "black"))
```

Comment: Not sure what you want tbh. Can you provide an example?

Comment: It would be easier to help you if you would describe your data or add a reproducible example.

Comment: Hi Nick and Maria. I am sorry: I just shared some code that may be of help. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

I may have misunderstood, but perhaps this type of approach would work for your use-case?

```r
library(tidyverse)

draft <- structure(list(Player = c("Shaquil Delos", "Shaquil Delos", "Shaquil Delos", 
                                   "Shaquil Delos", "Shaquil Delos", "Shaquil Delos", "Shaquil Delos", 
                                   "Shaquil Delos", "Shaquil Delos", "Shaquil Delos", "Shaquil Delos", 
                                   "Shaquil Delos", "Shaquil Delos", "Shaquil Delos", "Shaquil Delos", 
                                   "Shaquil Delos"), Date = structure(c(19371, 19370, 19369, 19368, 
                                                                        19367, 19364, 19363, 19362, 19361, 19360, 19359, 19356, 19355, 
                                                                        19354, 19353, 19349), class = "Date"), week = c(29, 29, 29, 29, 
                                                                                                                        29, 28, 28, 28, 28, 28, 28, 27, 27, 27, 27, 26), TD = c(6638, 
                                                                                                                                                                                2660, 4761, 4956, 3984, 4001, 3688, 4476, 4616, 4666, 4120, 3782, 
                                                                                                                                                                                3701, 4398, 4275, 3222), Time = c(96, 67, 70, 75, 38, 33, 55, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                  68, 59, 57, 56, 35, 45, 56, 46, 21), Vmax = c(9.4, 4.7, 8.3, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                8.8, 6.9, 9.5, 6.5, 6, 9.2, 7.1, 7.3, 9, 6.5, 6.8, 6.2, 4.6), 
                        Amax = c(4.5, 3.1, 4.1, 4.9, 3.8, 3.8, 4.4, 3.9, 4.5, 4.4, 
                                 4, 3.4, 4.3, 3.5, 3.2, 1.5), Dmax = c(-5.9, -2.8, -4.2, -6.2, 
                                                                       -3.9, -2.7, -4.9, -3.5, -2.7, -4.6, -3.5, -2.7, -4.5, -3.7, 
                                                                       -3.8, -1.4), Aerobic = c(462, 44, 589, 280, 175, 546, 333, 
                                                                                                831, 303, 959, 225, 125, 194, 188, 534, 665), HSD = c(177, 
                                                                                                                                                      0, 475, 86, 59, 463, 56, 14, 384, 92, 119, 393, 54, 262, 
                                                                                                                                                      24, 0), SD = c(100, 0, 78, 39, 0, 149, 0, 0, 125, 3, 6, 141, 
                                                                                                                                                                     0, 0, 0, 0), Nsprints = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
                                                                                                                                                                                               0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), DEC3 = c(7, 0, 2, 5, 0, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         0, 8, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0), ACC3 = c(4, 0, 1, 4, 0, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    0, 9, 0, 3, 4, 0, 0, 9, 0, 0, 0), RHIE = c(15, 3, 19, 10, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               5, 5, 17, 6, 6, 10, 10, 3, 10, 5, 5, 2), MIP1 = c(161, 112, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 169, 147, 184, 285, 162, 266, 170, 248, 197, 222, 167, 177, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 232, 254), MIP3 = c(359, 309, 375, 345, 535, 738, 431, 688, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     479, 709, 531, 549, 476, 461, 662, 724), MIP5 = c(565, 473, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       560, 537, 868, 1049, 589, 851, 673, 1152, 845, 875, 682, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       619, 983, 1166), ACC = c(78, 14, 64, 46, 27, 20, 51, 32, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                29, 56, 40, 12, 45, 26, 21, 0), ACC2 = c(18, 1, 14, 15, 3, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         9, 24, 9, 16, 12, 9, 6, 25, 4, 3, 0), DEC = c(67, 11, 42, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       48, 23, 14, 36, 22, 14, 49, 32, 7, 30, 20, 15, 0), DEC2 = c(21, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   0, 12, 14, 5, 0, 20, 4, 0, 11, 4, 0, 16, 1, 2, 0), Explosive = c(12, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    9, 15, 13, 5, 1, 45, 11, 3, 8, 16, 0, 14, 11, 6, 0), TRIMP = c(107, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   0, 78, 51, 105, 60, 85, 93, 55, 93, 102, 44, 89, 110, 109, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   47), TRIMP4 = c(0, 0, 3, 12, 20, 8, 0, 0, 0, 13, 1, 2, 2, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   15, 17, 15), TRIMP5 = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           0, 0, 0, 0, 0), TD.min = c(69.3, 39.9, 68.1, 66, 103.6, 121.4, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      67.2, 65.7, 78.7, 82.1, 77.5, 109.3, 82.5, 78.8, 92.8, 151
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           ), HRavg = c(66, 0, 65, 65, 79, 69, 67, 65, 60, 67, 74, 70, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        71, 71, 75, 73), Vmax.perc = c(100, 50, 88, 93, 73, 101, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       69, 64, 98, 75, 78, 95, 70, 72, 66, 49), Amax.perc = c(88, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              62, 80, 96, 74, 75, 86, 77, 89, 87, 78, 67, 85, 68, 63, 30
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       ), Dmax.perc = c(104, 50, 74, 109, 69, 48, 85, 61, 47, 81, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        61, 47, 79, 65, 66, 25)), row.names = c("21", "211", "22", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                "19", "191", "2", "20", "212", "201", "213", "221", "1", "11", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                "202", "203", "18"), class = "data.frame")

for (i in 4:31) {

print(ggplot(draft, aes(x=draft[,2], y=draft[,i])) +
  geom_bar(stat="identity",fill="navyblue") + 
  geom_text(label=as.integer(draft[,i]), size=5-nchar(as.integer(draft[3,i])),
            vjust=1.2, colour = "white",fontface=2) +
  labs(title = paste("Session trends for", colnames(draft)[i],"-", "player"))+
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 0,color="black",size=8),
        axis.title.x = element_blank(),
        axis.title.y = element_blank(),
        plot.title = element_text(color="black", size=10, face="bold",hjust = 0.5),
        legend.position = "none",
        panel.grid.major = element_blank(),
        panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
        panel.background = element_blank(), 
        axis.line = element_line(colour = "black")))
}
```

[image][image][image][image][image][image][image][image][image][image][image][image][image][image][image][image][image][image][image][image][image][image][image][image][image][image]

<sup>Created on 2023-01-16 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: Hi Jared. First of all, thank you so much for your help. It seemd correct, but the problem is that what I am looking for is not the size of the labels to be adjusted to the number of characters of the string (nchar), but to the number of bars that the loop generates, which depend on the number of rows that the "draft" dataframe contains.
In this case, the dataframe contains 16 rows, then 16 bars are created and hence, the labels should be smaller than if the dataframe contained 5 rows, in which only 5 bars by graph would be created. Do you know what I try to ask? I am not sure if it is clear

Comment: Ahh - that makes sense - you could use something like `size=0.2 * length(draft[,i])` but you would need to work out the scale yourself (i.e. does `0.2 * length` or `1 + (0.1 * length)` 'work better'; it's hard to figure this out without an example dataset illustrating your actual use-case (if you have some draft dataframes with 5 rows, and some with 16 rows, and some with 30, then create your example dataset to reflect that)

Comment: Hi jared. Yeah, I think that this may be the best solution. I was figuring out if there would be any option to adjust the size of the label to the width of the bar instead of the number of bars (where the more bars, the narrower, and the less bars, the wider), but I guess this is a good alternative I can try. Thank you for your help!